# Less Objectifying Than If

Tags: meaning

> KATIE COURIC: Some newswomen dress like they’re going clubbing.
>
> [RACHEL MADDOW:](http://www.glamour.com/magazine/2011/05/rachel-maddow-tells-katie-couric-im-not-competing-on-the-pretty-girl-on-cable-front) It’s un-businesslike. … But there’s an interesting question in there: If you make a decision about trying to succeed on the basis of your looks, **is it less objectifying than if it’s somebody else’s decision?**

Could someone please elucidate the bold sentence? [Definition of objectify as a  transitive verb](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/objectify?q=objectifying):

1. express (something abstract) in a concrete form:
2. degrade to the status of a mere object:

Is the apt definition #2? If so, does the bold sentence mean:
Is [ making a decision about trying to succeed on the basis of your looks ] less demeaning/degrading [ of those newswomen who dress inappositely ]
when it's somebody else's decision ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition 2 is correct. When you or someone else emphasises your looks and physical attractiveness over your character and skills, you are turned to some degree in a mere object of people's physical attraction and desire, instead of being an agent, a subject yourself—or so says the newswoman.

Your paraphrase is not correct: you left out *than*. To edit your paraphrase:

> Is [ making a decision about trying to succeed on the basis of your looks ] less demeaning/degrading [ of those newswomen who dress inappositely ]
> **than** when it's somebody else's decision ?

The difference is that what you said means the opposite of the original.

> If you use an umbrella (A), you get *less* wet **than** if you hold a newspaper over your head (B).
>
> With am umbrella (A), you get *less* wet **than** with a newspaper (B).

As you see, situations A (using an umbrella) and B (holding a newspaper over your head) are opposites. The two opposites in the quotation are:

- if you present yourself as a mere pretty thing by using your looks to boost your career as a newswoman
- if someone else treats you as a mere pretty thing by giving you a promotion based only on your looks

The question she asks is, "is situation A less objectifying than B?". So are you turned into a mere object of sexual attraction (as opposed to your mind and skills) less if you do it yourself than if someone else does it?

Comment: +1. Many thanks. Two supplementaries : 1. Could you please clarify to what situations A & B refer ? 2. How and why are the 2 statements in your 2nd box opposite to each other ? The 2nd sentence in your 2nd box can be construed as *With an umbrella, you get less wet than with a newspaper [over your head].*

Comment: @LePressentiment: Ad 1: I have added references to A and B in the text, is this clearer? Ad 2: I don't understand your question. You can choose to protect yourself from the rain either by using an umbrella or by using a newspaper. Those two are opposites in that they are mutually exclusive options in the given situation: it makes no sense to hold *both* over your head at the same time. The way the 2nd sentence "can be construed" is exactly as it as intended: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Yes, it helps prodigiously ! I now register the relevance of the second box. However, in the second box, why did you present two sentences to illustrate situation A (the subordinate clause at the beginning of both sentences in the 2nd box) vs situation B (the independent clause)? The two sentences appear to say the same?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Yes, they mean the same thing. I added the second sentence in order to remove the *if* clauses, because those made the sentence more complex. They made it harder to grasp the essential construction at a glance, while not being essential themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I deeply appreciate your instructive, thorough answers and expeditious comments.